How to raise numerical labels on a matplotlib bar plot
points_1_25 = {'Completed' : grades_simple_completed, 'Failed': grades_simple_failed}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 10))
bottom = np.zeros(25)
width = 0.8
for verdict, point in points_1_25.items():
    p = ax.bar(x_labels, point, width, label=verdict, bottom=bottom)
    bottom += point
    ax.bar_label(p, label_type='center',color='w', fontsize=20)
ax.set_facecolor("gray")
ax.set_title('Some label', fontsize=25)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=20)
ax.set_ylim([0, 11])
ax.legend(prop={'size': 20}, loc='lower center')

On a bar plot generated from this code I want to have numerical labels a little bit higher, for example, 20 pixels higher than they are now (see the picture for a better understanding). Is there a way to do it?


you should provide grades_simple_completed and grades_simple_failed for reproducibility

@mozway it's from a file and sort of NDA. Does the content of the lists affect the method to put the labels higher if there is one?

ax.bar_label(...., padding=30) seems to work for your case.  padding is measured in "points", which are 1/72 of an inch (the figsize is set in inches). "points" is also how fontsize is measured.

Please add some dummy test data. Don't ask answerers to invent their own test data. That way, you prevent people losing time to try to find out the exact data format you were using.  A bit too frequent, when answerers provide their own test data, the original poster complains that it doesn't work in their case.
